# Block POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1

Tags: php, opencart, cpanel, whm, ddos

I want to block attacks of the form:

POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1

either globally in whm firewall or per account (htaccess or php).

I have tried adding to the index.php of admin

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
if (empty($_GET)) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 405 Method Not Allowed", true);
    exit;
 }
}
```

or

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   if (empty($_GET)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit;
 }
}
```

with no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: With such codes you will only deny access to your php code, but server and web-server are open to attack. Which OS do you use?

Comment: CLOUDLINUX 7.9 kvm [web] v98.0.9        Server Version: Apache/2.4.51 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.1.1l Apache mod_bwlimited/1.4

Comment: Do you have any firewall installed on your system?

Comment: `.htaccess` file in `/admin/`: `<LimitExcept GET>Deny from all</LimitExcept>`. Does that work?

Comment: @Sohrab Yes, I have csf v14.11, mod_security with paid rules by GotRoot.

Comment: @Jacob Mulquin I will try it now...

Comment: @Jacob Mulquin .htaccess rule does not work for me.

Comment: I think the only solution is mod security rules that will block the user agent which is always the same and the request which is always POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1